# Get scons to generate a new build number

Tags: c++, scons, build-numbers

I'd like to get scons to read a previous version number from a file, update a source file with a new version number and current date and then write the number back to the original file ready for the next build.

This needs to happen *only* when the target is out of date. IOW the version number doesn't change if no build takes place. The original file is source controlled and *isn't* a source file else it could trigger another build on check-in (due to CI). **CLARIFICATION** From scons' point of view the code will always be out of date due to the auto-generated source file but scons will only be run from a Continuous Integration job (Jenkins) when a SCM change is detected.

I've looked into `AddPostMethod`, but this seems to fire for all files within the list of source files.
`Command` and `Builder` methods use the `VARIANT_DIR` so I can't edit these files and then check them back in as they no longer map to the repo.

I'm hoping I'm just misunderstanding some of the finer details of scons else I'm running out of ideas!

**Update**
Thinking this through some more, Tom's comment is correct. Although I have two files, one version controlled text file (non-source code) and one non-source controlled source file there is no way to check one file in and prevent a continuous build/check-in cycle. Jenkins will see the new text file and spin off a build, and scons will see the new generated file. So unless I delete the generated file at some point, although this seems to go against the workflow of both tools.

Does anyone have any method for achieving this? It seems pretty straightforward. Ultimately I just want to generate build numbers each time a build is started.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. It seems to me that you'll always trigger a rebuild like that, Because once you complete a build after something has changed, then you "update a source file with the new number and date", And then the next time you do a build, the source file has changed. So it causes a new build.

Comment: @TomTanner correct except the file won't be checked in therefore CI (Jenkins in this case) won't detect the change and run scons. But you're right from an scons point of view the source has changed. I'll make that more clear in the question.

Comment: You can always do nothing in the post action if the source doesn't match the one you want?

Comment: I did go down that route but it felt like I was trying to bend the post action method to do something it wasn't designed to do. I may take another look...

Comment: you should be able to do `AddPostAction('magic source file.o', func)` if I'm reading the documentation correctly, but I've never used a post action, so I'm not entirely sure

Comment: Ah that may work better. I was using `AddPostAction(someProgram, func)` which explains why I was seeing it run for every source file rather than the single.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32760/discussion-between-adam-naylor-and-tom-tanner)

Answer (score 1):

From [SCons User Guide section 8, Order-Only Dependencies](http://www.scons.org/doc/2.3.1/HTML/scons-user.html#idm10916352), you can use the `Requires` method:

```
import time

# put whatever text you want in your version.c; this is just regular python
version_c_text = """
char *date = "%s";
""" % time.ctime(time.time())
open('version.c', 'w').write(version_c_text)

version_obj = Object('version.c')

hello = Program('hello.c',
                LINKFLAGS = str(version_obj[0]))

Requires(hello, version_obj)
```

Two things to note: first you have to add the explicit `Requires` dependency.  Second, you can't make version_obj a source of the Program builder, you have to cheat (here we pass it as a linkflag), otherwise you'll get an automatic full dependency on it.

This will update the version.c always, but won't rebuild just because version.c changed.